# Android studio: Failed to complete Gradle execution

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i had same issue that mention in [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27407855/android-studio-failed-to-complete-gradle-execution-cause-is-empty), 
when i tried to run my project the error dialog show:
[image: Run error dialog]

i already do to the same thing in that site to resolve the problem 
but it didnt work for me

this is the folowing thing that i have do to resolve this problem:
1. set JAVA_HOME to right path
2. add -Xmx256m Gradle VM option or higher
 
3. clean the project but... the project cant be cleaned and show the same error dialog as Run Project error dialog

this my log :

```
03-29 07:05:48.993    2621-2644/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
03-29 07:05:48.994    2621-2644/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
03-29 07:05:49.003    2621-2644/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
03-29 07:05:49.065    2621-2644/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley D/:HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xafe0b770, tid  2644
03-29 07:05:49.454    2621-2644/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley   I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-29 07:05:49.504    2621-2644/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
03-29 07:05:49.521    2621-2644/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley    W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-29 07:05:49.521    2621-2644/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xafe08f40, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-29 07:05:49.622    2621-2644/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-29 07:05:49.623    2621-2644/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xafe08f60, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-29 07:05:49.701    2621-2621/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 61 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-29 07:05:56.280    2621-2621/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley D/Volley﹕ [1] 2.onErrorResponse: MainActivity
03-29 07:05:56.348    2621-2621/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley D/Volley﹕ [1] Request.finish: 7671 ms: [ ] http://10.0.3.2/sinDicel/json/movies1.json 0x1e7db5ea NORMAL 1
03-29 07:08:20.158    2621-2631/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley I/art﹕ Debugger is no longer active
```

Please help i need to finish my project soon

Thanks

Comment: Should i Reinstall the Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Restartet Android Studio, restartet PC?

Sounds stupid but you know...you never know^^

After that, maybe try to import your project to Android Studio.

No more ideas then, so reinstall it if it still wont work. Including the SDK.

Still doesn't work? Reinstall java.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the cause was an apostrophe in the strings.xml resource file.

For example changing this:

```
    <string name="edit_message">Don't do this</string>
```

To:

```
    <string name="edit_message">But this</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should restarted your computer and Android Studio. Download latest gradle.