# Failed to complete gradle execution. Cause is empty. 65K Methods Limit

Tags: android, build.gradle

This is de build.gradle of app module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.my.app"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 19
    versionName "1.6.2"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        debuggable false;
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),  'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/'] } }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'http://dl.bintray.com/madcyph3r/maven/'  }
    maven { url 'http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'net.glxn.qrgen:android:2.0'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'de.madcyph3r:materialDrawer:1.1.1@aar'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
    compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.7'
    compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
    compile files('libs/GraphView-4.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/mpandroidchartlibrary-2-1-0.jar')
    compile files('libs/bitcoinj-core-0.12.3-bundled.jar')

}
```

And this is build.gradle of project

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to      all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

I'm trying use Google cloud Messaging , I have followed all steps in https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client but when I synchronize gradle files with the project I get this:

```
Failed to complete gradle execution. Cause: [empty]
```

I tried implement this solution: [Android Studio: failed to complete gradle execution, cause is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27407855/android-studio-failed-to-complete-gradle-execution-cause-is-empty) and other similar solutions but result is same.

What could be the solution to this problem? Someone has happened this?

Thaanks in advance!!

Comment: Does this affect other projects (not involving GCM) that you try to build with Android Studio?

Comment: No, I have created other apps and Android Studio compiles fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

The problem lies not in GCM. The problem arises when I try to compile the app. I used the command;

```
gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace
```

and I threw this error:

```
Unable to execute dex : method ID not in [0 , 0xFFFF ] : 65536.
```

I've solved with the steps described Google here:
[Building Apps with Over 65K Methods](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#mdex-gradle)

Comment: for sake of simplicity, please list down here the points... As link contents could change over time..